# Host and port needed to access google bigquery and cloud storage

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to test bq and gsutil from a data center where external network access is blocked by default. What are the hosts and ports that need to be opened up in order to access bigquery and cloud storage?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reach the BigQuery API and OAuth API endpoints using a standard HTTPS connection (i.e. port 443).

Comment: So port is 443. Where would I find the host IP or DNS? I am trying to use JDBC connection to BigQuery using Simba and it needs the host info as well.